# Show picture when button is clicked

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to get my action listener to show a picture when the button is clicked, but hide it until then. I also need it to only allow me to click it once. I have the button in a separate class that extends JButton so I'm unsure if that is affecting it. When I add the image using the action listener, it doesn't show the image whether I click it or not. When I add it to the button, it shows it before it is clicked(as expected). What is the best way to hide the image until the button is clicked? FYI, there are many instances of this button created, if that makes a difference.

This is the button class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class EmptyButton extends JButton
{
    public EmptyButton()
    {
        //add image to button
        ImageIcon emptyImage = new ImageIcon("Empty.jpg");
        JLabel empty = new JLabel(emptyImage);
        
    }
}
```

This is the action listener

```
    private class emptyButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            game.noTreasureFound();
            treasuresFoundTextField.setText(String.valueOf(game.getTreasuresFound()));
            treasuresLeftTextField.setText(String.valueOf(20-game.getTreasuresFound()));
            triesLeftTextField.setText(String.valueOf(game.getTriesLeft()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't add a JLabel to a button. Instead, set the Icon of the button when it is clicked.

Comment: 1) 1st, make sure you can load an image and display it (without any button click. 2) [Edit] to add a [mre]. 3) Hotlink to the image, or create it at run-time. 4) Use `getResource` to obtain an URL pointing to the image. 5) Use `ImageIO` to load the image (it provides helpful feedback).

Answer (score -1):

1. use `JLabel#setVisible(true)` to make image visible on click. Initially call `setVisible(false)` to hide it
2. use `JButton#setEnabled(false)` to disable button after click

Comment: When I do that, it says setVisible is an undeclared method

Comment: its on Jlabel sorry.